# Problem when installing 12.04 on Windows 8.1 PC - grub rescue

Tags: 12.04, boot, dual-boot, grub2, system-installation

My Dad's PC was having problems.  I think it was a mistake to get Windows 8.1 installed in the first place, to be honest.  It's way too fussy.

Anyway, he was about to wipe the entire thing, and I suggested having a look at Ubuntu.

I did the following:

- Tried to install via download from Firefox... but his PC was so flaky I couldn't be sure what was going on at times.  Lots of pop ups etc. despite adblock being installed.
- I created an Ubuntu trial DVD and ran that.  He liked the look of it, so from within that I installed 12.04.
- When it restarted I got a grub rescue prompt.  I have literally no idea what to do next.

It says :

```
error: no such device: 4376b2fc-07c9-4e08-bc3c-b8e41dfd8888.
grub rescue>
```

I had hoped to have a dual boot option at start-up, and then from Ubuntu was hoping to be able to move files from the Windows partition.

I'd be grateful for any advice.

I ran a couple of commands using the Ubuntu loader DVD.

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo parted -l
Model: ATA WDC WD5000AAKX-0 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 500GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End    Size    Type      File system  Flags
 1      32.3kB  370MB  370MB   primary   ntfs         boot
 3      370MB   484GB  484GB   primary   ntfs
 4      484GB   493GB  8678MB  primary   ntfs
 2      493GB   500GB  7043MB  extended
 5      493GB   500GB  7041MB  logical   fat32


Model: SanDisk Cruzer (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdc: 4022MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
 1      19.5kB  4014MB  4014MB  primary  fat32


Model: Generic STORAGE DEVICE (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdd: 2033MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start  End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
 1      127kB  2031MB  2031MB  primary  fat16


Model: Seagate Expansion Desk (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdi: 2000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End     Size    Type      File system     Flags
 1      1049kB  1006GB  1006GB  primary   ntfs
 2      1006GB  2000GB  995GB   extended
 5      1006GB  1997GB  991GB   logical   ext4
 6      1997GB  2000GB  3706MB  logical   linux-swap(v1)


Warning: Unable to open /dev/sr0 read-write (Read-only file system).  /dev/sr0
has been opened read-only.
Error: Can't have a partition outside the disk!   

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders, total 976773168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xb1c44ea9

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *          63      722924      361431    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2       963016425   976773167     6878371+   5  Extended
/dev/sda3          722925   946067849   472672462+   7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda4       946067850   963016424     8474287+   7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda5       963016488   976768064     6875788+  bc  Unknown

Partition table entries are not in disk order

Disk /dev/sdc: 4022 MB, 4022337024 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 489 cylinders, total 7856127 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x2c49399c

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdc1              38     7839719     3919841    b  W95 FAT32

Disk /dev/sdd: 2032 MB, 2032664576 bytes
64 heads, 63 sectors/track, 984 cylinders, total 3970048 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x45242cb8

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdd1             249     3967487     1983619+   6  FAT16

Disk /dev/sdi: 2000.4 GB, 2000398933504 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 243201 cylinders, total 3907029167 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000dfc2d

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdi1            2048  1964583671   982290812    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sdi2      1964584958  3907028991   971222017    5  Extended
/dev/sdi5      1964584960  3899789311   967602176   83  Linux
/dev/sdi6      3899791360  3907028991     3618816   82  Linux swap / Solaris
```

Comment: When you installed ubuntu did you select the option to install along with windows8???

Comment: Yep - The idea I had was to have both available upon boot.  On my laptop at home I have it defaulting to 12.04, but I could switch to Vista if I was feeling like hurting myself.  That process was pretty straightforward but on my dad's computer it became complex, and quick.....I'm half convinced that the constant pop-ups etc. have somehow caused me to make an error.

Answer (score 0):

Try to reinstall the grub by using an Ubuntu Alternate CD. If not, try to burn on a DVD Boot-Repair.

I too had problem with Win 8.1 and Ubuntu. Especially on UEFI Device, sometimes Windows just doesn't want Linux to install side by side with secure boot on.

Comment: Thank you - it certainly wasn't as simple as my home setup (old Vista laptop now running brilliantly on 12.04) and no hassles on installation.

Comment: Does this info help?